# Save the contents of a textarea into a text file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In a little Sinatra app I'm working on, I want to store what I write in a textarea into a text file. What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `post` handler (you have it, right?) just dump whatever has been passed through your form field into a file:

```
post '/' do
  File.open('name_of_the_file.txt', 'w') do |f|
    f.write params[:name_of_your_textarea]
  end
end
```

Comment: I did *exactly* that, but when I try it on the localhost, it gives me a 404, which is completely insane!

Comment: You should check whether the path of the page you are submitting the form to matches the handler path.

Comment: it does. I even rewrote it to double check.

Comment: How do you start Sinatra and are you pointing your browser to the right port?

Comment: How to pop a window for user to choose the path of file?